# Making InlineObjectElement read-only

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

Is there an easy way to make generated InlineObjectElements read-only? I'm thinking of using a custom ReadOnlySectionProvider. Is there a way to get a TextSegment from a InlineObjectElement that is kept updated? Or do I need to create my own TextSegment from the InlineObjectElement? If so how do I get the TextSegment start and end offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InlineObjectElement` is generated on-demand only while the text line is in the visible area. Making the `InlineObjectElement` read-only thus would not prevent it from being deleted if the user scrolls away before pressing Del.

You'll have to write an `IReadOnlySectionProvider` implementation that matches your `VisualElementGenerator` so that you can protect the pieces of text that will cause the inline element to be generated.

---

If you really need to know the start/end offsets of an existing `InlineObjectElement`:

```
int start = parentVisualLine.StartOffset + element.RelativeTextOffset;
int end = start + element.DocumentLength;
```

If you don't know the start offset of the parent `VisualLine`, there's no way to determine the offset. But you should always know it, given that you either created the element yourself in a generator (in which case it's `context.VisualLine`) or found the element in the `parentVisualLine.Elements` collection.